# How to open right Screen Lock Settings?

Tags: android, settings, lockscreen, huawei-mobile-services

My Android app requires a screen lock, so that `KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure` will return true. If a screen lock is missing, I want the make the user aware, that a screen lock is required and present a button, that opens the screen lock settings.

As in post "[Intent to launch fingerprint enrollment screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526631/intent-to-launch-fingerprint-enrollment-screen)" described, the screen lock setting is located at another locatioin for some devices (e.g. Huawei P9).

Depending on the device I should open `Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS` or `Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS`. Is there a way to determine what to use on which device?

Comment: I share this question - I didn't see an intent to open the Settings specifically in the Screen Lock category.

Comment: please refer stackoverflow.com/a/44154805